# Could not write JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, resttemplate

Getting this error :

> nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct
>   self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   com.google.gson.JsonObject["asJsonObject"])

when trying to do this :

```
 restTemplate.postForObject(url_final, convertedObject, Object[].class);
```

where `convertedObject` is a `JSONObject` and `urlfinal` is a `String` url.

Payload is:

```
"data" : [
  {"FILENAME":"EEC1.TXT",
   "ERRORDESCRIPTION":"FTD-07-INVALID CHARACTER FOUND IN THE FILE.",
   "LINENO":3},
  {"FILENAME":"SEC1.TXT",
   "ERRORDESCRIPTION":"26-FTD-07-INVALID CHARACTER FOUND IN THE FILE.",
    "LINENO":447}]
```

My Code:

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject(payload);
JSONArray jsonArray = output.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject objects = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String fileName = objects.getString("FILENAME");
int lineNumber = objects.getInt("LINENO");
String errordesc = objects.getString("ERRORDESCRIPTION");
String tempor = "{\"activityType\": \"trial.start\",\"aFileName\":\""  
              + fileName
              + "\",\"aLINENO\": \""
              + lineNumber
              + "\",\"aREFNO\": \"" 
              + TxnNo
              + "\",    \"aERRORDESCRIPTION\": \""+errordesc+"\"}";
JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(tempor, JsonObject.class);
restTemplate.postForObject(url_final, convertedObject, Object[].class);
```

Comment: Could you please add code snippet here what you have tired

Comment: @DulajKulathunga : Have added.Can you check now?

Comment: Please include the complete stacktrace, not just the message.

Comment: The exception message and your code don't add up. The exception indicates you're using _Jackson_ (`com.fasterxml.jackson...`) while your code is using _Gson_ (`new Gson()`). Why are you mixing the two? In general you shouldn't pass a generic `JsonObject` to a parser/formatter that doesn't know about those implementations - and Jackson and Gson won't know each other's classes.

Comment: Why are you creating JSON by hand which then is parsed and reserialized in the first place? Why don't you use a proper pojo or at least a map which then is serialized?

Comment: @Thomas : Have only imported jackson but not using it. Was wondering why this error.

Comment: Well, you _are_ using Jackson... it's Jackson that's complaining about not being able to properly serialize Gson's `JsonObject`. You'd either have to provide some (probably extensive) serialization hints/config for `JsonObject` etc. or just do it another way.

Comment: @Thomas : Any idea on another way to do this?

Comment: I've already suggested two in a comment above: 1) use a proper pojo or 2) at least a map and serialize that.

Answer (score 1):

In ten lines you mixed up 3 different `JSON` libraries:

- `JSONObject` comes from [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).
- `Gson` comes from Google's [gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson).
- `restTemplate` uses behind the scene [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind).

You should skip first two and use only `Jackson`. Above code after changes could look like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

....

ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

JsonNode output = mapper.readTree(payload);

ArrayNode jsonArray = (ArrayNode)output.get("data");
JsonNode objects = jsonArray.get(0);
String fileName = objects.get("FILENAME").asText();
int lineNumber = objects.get("LINENO").asInt();
String errordesc = objects.get("ERRORDESCRIPTION").asText();
String tempor = "{\"activityType\": \"trial.start\",\"aFileName\":\""
        + fileName
        + "\",\"aLINENO\": \""
        + lineNumber
        + "\",\"aREFNO\": \""
        + TxnNo
        + "\",    \"aERRORDESCRIPTION\": \""+errordesc+"\"}";
JsonNode convertedObject = mapper.readTree(tempor);
```

Since version [2.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.0) you can use `JsonMapper.builder().build()` but in previous versions you can just create new instance by `new ObjectMapper()` which is also fine.

Comment: and with these modifications, we can use restTemplate.postForObject like above?

Comment: @Thira, yes, at the end put `restTemplate.postForObject(url_final, convertedObject, Object[].class);` line as you have in the code.

Comment: Ziober , I am getting this error while trying that    :  the import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper cannot be resolved

Comment: @Thira, this is why I wrote you can create instance `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` and remove `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;` line.

Comment: @Thira, have you fixed that problem?

Comment: Ziober , No. I am getting this exception now - org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode

Comment: @Thira, you should not use `org.json.*` classes at all. Take a look on my example where I show how to implement it only with `Jackson` classes.

Comment: @Ziober : Fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Thira, great to hear that. You can accept and upvote answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Ziober : Actually this method did not work. Another one did.